# Google Sign in for Web App using Apps Script Project - Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: google-apps-script, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

This is what I get after clicking on sign-in button.
[image]

I have created a google cloud project in https://console.cloud.google.com/ and then setup
web client, I have not added JavaScript origins( I don't know if apps Script web app URL i should put here?) and from [this github](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2) I got that redirect URL would be "https://script.google.com/macros/d/{script_id}/usercallback". The script_id is my apps script id.

What is proper way to setup Google web Client setup to use Google Sign in into Web App created using apps script project?

I am definidately missing lot of stuff.

JavaScript file JS003.html file has following code:

```js
<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser)
{
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  $(".g-signin2").css("display","none");
  $(".data").css("display","block");
  $("#pic").attr('src',profile.getImageUrl());
  $("#email").text(profile.getEmail());

  logInfo(profile);

}

function SignOut()
{
  var auth2= gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
  auth2.signOut().then(function(){
    alert("You have been successfully signed out");
    $(".g-signin2").css("display","block");
    $(".data").css("display","none");
  });
}

function logInfo(profile){
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
}
  </script
```

My GS code file Code.gs has following functions:

```js
function doGet(){
  var index = "Index003";
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(index)
  .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

and HTML file Index003.html is as bellow:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="865560649437-1mi0ebrq8rb4rq9ejrrh3eouiics60f9.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    <div class="data">
      <p> Profile Details</p>
      <img id="pic" class="img-circle" width="100" height="100"/>
      <p>Email Address</p>
      <p id="email" class="alert alert-danger"></p>
      <button onclick="signOut()" class="btn btn-danger"></button>
    </div>

   <!-- Script -->
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?!= include('JS003') ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS file CSS003.html

```css
<style>
.g-signin2{
  margin-left:500px;
  margin-top:200px;
}

  </style
```

Comment: This is the apps script project I am testing for google sign-in, incase anyone want to have a look for quick access. Only relevant files are with post fix 003: https://script.google.com/d/1JNHRvHS3DkT_ASITai2Y86PaVI6LvAD4paPSqTUXQ6VXFBPKR_7cp-hV/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why are you trying to implement your own client side sign in? If the user visits the web app and you have deployed as "Anyone with Google Account", it should take care of the sign in automatically.

Comment: @iansedano, Thank for pointing that out. I have now deployed with access to 'anyone'. But still I get the same error. Then I deployed with 'Anyone with Google Account' option - but still problem is same. my doubt is there anything in console project I have to change.

Comment: @iansedano, I am building an webapp for my customer who needs signin /signout for his limited customer/vendors only.

Comment: Ah ok. So you want to restrict access to certain people? Are all these people in the same domain, i.e same Workspace account?

Comment: @iansedano, users are random, some are domain users such as security, while customer, supports are outside domain. Some tech-supports are domain users.

Comment: And you need to use their google account to sign in, or can you give them their own login?